# How to display pagination in my XSLT when displaying picture gallery

Tags: 2013, list-view, xslt, picture-library

I have a page named PictureGallery.aspx in which I am displaying a picture gallery as shown in screenshot below.
[image]

I have applied XSLT on this gallery and displaying it according to how I want it which is working fine.

But problem is it displays all pictures on one page. I want to show pagination on this page. If I pass parameter to this page as below, how can I make my picture gallery only display certain items per page?

```
PictureGallery.aspx?page=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to picture library, from the ribbon click on library -> modify view -> item limit, you can set item limit accordingly.

Or else you can use DataView webpart in which you can modify XSLT according to your own requirement and implement paging which is quite easy.

Comment: Ok I tried to add data view web part but my picture library is not available in the list. Actually I am using variations and I have two sites English and Arabic. Picture library is created in English site so that's why it seems it is not available in root site when I try to add data view web part in SharePoint designer. What to do now?